# Deserialize value from XML-element by skipping parent in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, xmlserializer

Say I have a part of a XML file with a matrix layout with something similar to this:

**Matrix in XML**

```
<matrix>
 <row1>
   <col1>1.00</col1>
   <col2>0.00</col2>
   <col3>1.00</col3>
   <col4>1.00</col4>
 </row1>
 <row2>
   <col1>0.00</col1>
   <col2>1.00</col2>
   <col3>1.00</col3>
   <col4>0.00</col4>
 </row2>
</matrix>
```

And say id like to end up with a struct like this:

**Desired struct**

```
public struct sMatrix
{
    public float m11;
    public float m12;
    public float m13;
    ...
    public float m23;
    public float m24;
}
```

how should i declare this struct to be able to deserialize via XmlSerializer? Is there some Xml attribute i can give the floats in the struct to tell them that, for instance,`m11` is a child of row1? I tried this:`[XmlElement("matrix/row1/col1")` but it didnt work.

Comment: in case that the number of columns is not static (not always 4) i would recommend you another data structure. you cannot add properties during runtime.

Comment: They are static, the actual matrix is 6x6, didn't feel like writing that much xml though :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could mark all the fields of your matrix struct as non-serializable, and introduce a "Row" structure to serialize and deserialize your rows, like so:

```
[Serializable]
public struct sMatrixRow
{
    public sMatrixRow(float col1, float col2, float col3, float col4)
    {
        this.col1 = col1;
        this.col2 = col2;
        this.col3 = col3;
        this.col4 = col4;
    }
    public float col1;
    public float col2;
    public float col3;
    public float col4;
}

[Serializable]
public struct sMatrix
{
    [XmlElement("row1")]
    public sMatrixRow Row1
    {
        get
        {
            return new sMatrixRow(m00, m01, m02, m03);
        }
        set
        {
            this.m00 = value.col1;
            this.m01 = value.col2;
            this.m02 = value.col3;
            this.m03 = value.col4;
        }
    }

    // And so on, for Rows 2 through 4

    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m00;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m01;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m02;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m03;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m10;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m11;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m12;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m13;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m20;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m21;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m22;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m23;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m30;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m31;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m32;
    [System.NonSerialized, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
    public float m33;
}
```

Update: this scheme successfully serializes and deserializes the following "matrix" field in a containing class:

```
  <matrix>
    <row1>
      <col1>2</col1>
      <col2>0</col2>
      <col3>0</col3>
      <col4>0</col4>
    </row1>
    <row2>
      <col1>0</col1>
      <col2>2</col2>
      <col3>0</col3>
      <col4>0</col4>
    </row2>
    <row3>
      <col1>0</col1>
      <col2>0</col2>
      <col3>2</col3>
      <col4>0</col4>
    </row3>
    <row4>
      <col1>0</col1>
      <col2>0</col2>
      <col3>0</col3>
      <col4>1</col4>
    </row4>
  </matrix>
```

Is that what you want?

Update: added [XmlElement("row1")] to Row1 (and similarly for the other rows) to downcase the row names.  What I  am basically doing here is using serializable properties to create an XML-visible representation of your data that differs from, but is isomorphic to, the underlying fields.

Comment: Well, what I do want it to deserialize a XML which I can't control the layout for.. so in this case the actual serialization is nothing I'm concered about.